# I have a problem with brush seems to work inverted

Tags: sculpting

There is a problem with Blender, the brushes seem to work inverted.
I deleted Blender several times but it didn't work.

I hope the following video clearly shows the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nbzt9UwqQos

{edit}

I try the default sculpting scene same problem

Normals are not inverted

I did a Load factory settings

I think the problem is from a bug and I have uninstalled Blender and reinstalled it and the problem still exists

Comment: Is that default sculpting scene? Is the face orientation is correct? Have you tried File → Defaults → Load factory settings?

Comment: are you sure the normals are not inverted?

Comment: Normals are not inverted
I try the default sculpting scene same problem
I did a Load factory settings

Answer (score 0):

The pen was in the eraser position, which caused this stupid problem